# Checking if string in list exists in a different list of strings Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to check and see if a string in test_list2 is found in each string of test_list1. If a string in test_list2 is present in test_list1, then I want to append a 1 to a new list, else append a 0 to the same new list.

So:

```
test_list1 = [['Happy', 'Dog'], ['Sad', 'Dog'], ['Dog', 'Dog'], ['Angry', 'Dog']]
test_list2 = ['Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry']
new_list = []

def emotion_detection(x, y):
    for i in x:
        if i in y:
            new_list.append(1)
        if i not in y:
            new_list.append(0)
    print new_list
```

returns: [0, 0, 0, 0], when I think it should return [1,1,0,1]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: how is `emotion_detection` called? Please use meaningful names for `x` and `y`.

Comment: You may start by giving meaningful names to your variables in the function, starting with __x__ and __y__. E.g., one of them I would call __emotion_list__, another __tested_lists__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the logic behaviour you expect?

```
test_list1 = [['Happy', 'Dog'], ['Sad', 'Dog'], ['Dog', 'Dog'], ['Angry', 'Dog']]
test_list2 = ["Happy", "Sad", "Angry"]
new_list = []

def emotion_detection(x, y):
    for i in x:
        for string in i:
            if string in y:
                new_list.append(1)
                break
        else:
            new_list.append(0)
    print new_list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
emotions  = set(["Happy", "Sad", "Angry"])
sentences = ['Happy Dog', 'Sad Dog', 'Dog Dog', 'Angry Dog']

def is_emotional(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return bool(emotions.intersection(words))

sentence_emotions = [is_emotional(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
# gives [True, True, False, True]
```

**Edit:** Hackaholic has a good idea with `any`, but I would write it as

```
def is_emotional(sentence):
    return any(word in emotions for word in sentence.split())
```

which may be quicker, especially for long sentences, as it stops as soon as an emotion-word is found.

Comment: hey your and mine is approx same approach, expect `bool and any`. so I wonder which is faster bool or any??

Comment: Thank you! This really helps. I read in previous related threads that using "set"  instead of lists may help in conjunction with "intersection", but I wasn't sure how to apply it. This definitely clears up some misconceptions I had.

Answer (score 0):

```
test_list1 = [['Happy', 'Dog'], ['Sad', 'Dog'], ['Dog', 'Dog'], ['Angry', 'Dog']]
test_list2 = ["Happy", "Sad", "Angry"]
new_list = []

for element in test_list1:
    if element[0] in test_list2:
        new_list.append(1)
    else:
        new_list.append(0)
print new_list
```

instead of using `i`, use `i[0]` which is the index of emotion!

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
>>> test_list1 = [['Happy', 'Dog'], ['Sad', 'Dog'], ['Dog', 'Dog'],['Angry', 'Dog']]
>>> test_list2 = ["Happy", "Sad", "Angry"]
>>> [any(set(x)&set(test_list2)) for x in test_list1]
[True, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions:

```
new_list = [k[0] in test_list2 for k in test_list1]
```

Comment: Should be `[int(k[0] in test_list2) for k in test_list1]` to match OP's result types.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter.